# Does relation S is transitive

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Let S be relation whose representing matrix
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    1 & 0 & 1 \\
    1 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
Does relation S is transitive?

I write down relation S: $$S = \{(1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 3)\}$$
I have:$$(2, 1), (1, 3)∈ S\quad\And\quad(2, 3)∈ S$$

$$(2, 3), (3, 1)∈ S\quad\And\quad(2, 1)∈ S$$
So it should be transitive, but the answer is not. Where did i miss?

Comment: $(1,3),(3,1)\in S$ but $(1,1)\notin S$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $(1,3),(3,1) \in S$, but $(1,1)\not\in S$. You need to check **all** possible pairs.

Answer (score 0):

You missed that $(1,3),(3,1)\in S$, but $(1,1)\notin S$.